# Why it gives Node: 'model_8/dense_23/Relu' Matrix size-incompatible

Tags: hyperparameter-tuning

This is my code:

```py
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid
    from tensorflow.keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Dropout
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
    from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD, RMSprop, Adagrad, Adadelta, Adam, Adamax, Nadam
    from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
    
    
    # Define the hyperparameters to search
    
    param_grid = {
        'batch_size': [8, 16, 32],
        'optimizer': [SGD(), RMSprop(), Adagrad(), Adadelta(), Adam(), Adamax(), Nadam()],
        'epochs': [10, 50, 100]
    }
    
    best_score = 0.0
    best_params = {}
    
    # Perform grid search
    
    for params in ParameterGrid(param_grid):
        # Initializing the pre-trained model
        image_size = 229
        IMG_SHAPE = (image_size, image_size, 3)
    
        pre_trained_model = InceptionV3(
            input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
            include_top=False,
            weights='imagenet'
        )
    
        for layer in pre_trained_model.layers:
            layer.trainable = False
    
        last_layer = pre_trained_model.get_layer('mixed5')
        last_output = last_layer.output
    
        x = Flatten()(last_output)
    
        # Dense hidden layer
        x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
        x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
    
        # Output neuron.
        x = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x)
    
        model = Model(pre_trained_model.input, x)
    
        model.compile(optimizer=params['optimizer'], loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    
        # Train the model
        history = model.fit(
            train_generator,
            epochs=params['epochs'],
            steps_per_epoch=train_generator.samples // params['batch_size'],
            validation_data=validation_generator,
            validation_steps=validation_generator.samples // params['batch_size'],
            verbose=0
        )
    
        # Evaluate the model
        score = model.evaluate(validation_generator, steps=validation_steps, verbose=0)[1]
    
        # Check if this is the best score so far
        if score > best_score:
            best_score = score
            best_params = params
    
    # Print the best combination of hyperparameters
    print("Best: %f using %s" % (best_score, best_params))
    
    best_model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
    best_model.compile(optimizer=best_params['optimizer'], loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    best_model.fit(train_generator, epochs=best_params['epochs'])
    
    # Save the best model
    best_model.save('my_inceptionskinmodel.hdf5')
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.